# Axes disappear after drawing Networkx Graph on another subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I try to have a graph visualization on one subplot and a line plot of some values on another subplot. However, after I draw the graph on the first subplot, axes on the other subplot disappear (although I did not allow any shared axes). And I cannot bring them back.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
G = nx.graph_atlas(1)
nx.draw(G, ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

Results in:
[image]
While without `nx.draw()` it is:
[image]

I've tried calling `ax2.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)` after `nx.draw(G, ax=ax1)` but it has no effect.

**Q1:** How to restore the axes on `ax2`?
**Q2:** How is it possible that `nx.draw(G,ax=ax1)` affects `ax2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a bug in networkx. Instead of setting the ticklabels for the axes `ax` off, it calls `plt.tick_params(...)`. This will affect the currently active pyplot axes, which in your case is `ax2`.

So one option is to replace `plt.tick_params(` by `ax.tick_params(` in the source in lines [417](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/eb3a675c5b2b15e33b0a4a35bcee34d6b81ed94d/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L417) and [692](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/eb3a675c5b2b15e33b0a4a35bcee34d6b81ed94d/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L692) and [806](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/eb3a675c5b2b15e33b0a4a35bcee34d6b81ed94d/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L806) and [959](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/eb3a675c5b2b15e33b0a4a35bcee34d6b81ed94d/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L959) of `networkx/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py`.

I've just created a PR for that in https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/3476

---

The other option is to make sure the current pyplot axes is the one where your graph is in, e.g. via `plt.sca(ax1)`,

```
import networkx as nx
print(nx.__version__)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
G = nx.graph_atlas(1)
plt.sca(ax1)
nx.draw(G, ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```